# Convert JS email regex for unicode to swift?

Tags: javascript, swift, regex

How do you convert this js regex to swift:

```
var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
```

Comment: The regex you posted is supposed to be a string. You need to wrap it with quotes (ex: "yourregexhere"). Additionally, sometimes you might need to throw an escape character in. Xcode will tell you where to put it.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these simple conversion rules:

- Remove the leading `/` and the trailing `/` and everything after the trailing `/`
- Put the remaining expression in quotes `""` to make it a Swift string.
- Every instance of `\` needs to be escaped to be `\\`. But each instance of `\"` needs to be escaped as `\\\"`.

The `i` at the end (after the trailing `/` means that case is to be ignored. This means you need pass the proper option to ignore case when you use the `NSRegularExpression` class (or similar).

```
let re = "^(([^<>()\\[\\]\\.,;:\\s@\\\"]+(\\.[^<>()\\[\\]\\.,;:\\s@\\\"]+)*)|(\\\".+\\\"))@(([^<>()[\\]\\.,;:\\s@\\\"]+\\.)+[^<>()[\\]\\.,;:\\s@\\\"]{2,})$"
```